# HTML style, showing message start from bottom, but cannot be scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I would like to create a surface like wechat.. all message start from bottom, but why it doesn't scroll able? If message start from top, it was scroll able.. but I would like the message start from bottom..

How to improve my script? Thanks.

```js
     var childrens = document.querySelector("#chat").children.length;
     document.querySelector("#chat").childNodes[childrens-1].scrollIntoView()
```

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; background-position: top center; width: 100%; max-height: 1366px; position: relative;">
 <div style="height: 40px; background-color: black; color: white; line-height: 40px; position: fixed; top: 0px; width: 100%; z-index: 999" align="right">
  <div style="margin-right: 1em">menu</div>
 </div>
 <div style="bottom:0; background-color: white; color: white; line-height: 50px; position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 50px; z-index: 999; border-top: 1px solid #D3D3D3;" align="right">
  <div style="width: 100%">
   <div style="padding-left:1em; padding-right: 1em;" align="left"><input type="text" style="width: 90%;"><div style="float: right; border: 2px solid grey; height: 20px; margin-top: 0.5em; width: 20px; border-radius: 30px; color: grey; line-height: 20px; font-size: 1.5em;" align="center">+</div></div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div style="background-color: transparent; color: white; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;" align="right">
  <div style="padding-top: 40px; padding-right: 1em; padding-left: 1em; padding-bottom: 60px; position: absolute;">
   <div id="chat" style="width: 100%; color: black; padding-top: 1em; font-size: 12px;">
    <div>First message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Message here</div><div>Last message</div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would definitely recommend putting your CSS into a separate document instead of using hundreds of inline styles! It's much harder to debug and edit your code as it is.

Comment: yep, normally after I done my coding, will putting the style to CSS file..

Answer (score 0):

Give id "chat" to parent div of all messages and use this script

```
 <script>
     var childrens = document.querySelector("#chat").children.length;
     document.querySelector("#chat").childNodes[childrens-1].scrollIntoView() 
 </script>
```

Comment: Hi, I add this before the parent div showing `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of null`, if add after parent div showing `plugin.php?id=jnlegend:145 Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).childNodes[(childrens - 1)].scrollIntoView is not a function` .. I has been add the `id="chat"` to parent div

Comment: you have to give id chat to div which contain your parent div <div id="chat" style="width: 100%; color: black; padding-top: 1em; font-size: 12px;">
    <div>First message here</div>